# Unit Testing. What are the new Techniques/Tools in .NET 4.0?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, tdd

I'm doing some research on Unit Testing and most of the questions I see on Stack Overflow about NUnit are at least a year old now.  Are you using any new tools for Unit Testing that are available via Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0?  Please share any new technologies that you are aware of.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit is still one of the most popular unit testing frameworks out there. MsTest is also a popular framework because it is included by default with VS. If you want a framework that does its own thing you could look at [XUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/). One I have used in the past and enjoyed is [MbUnit](http://mb-unit.googlecode.com/).

In my opinion I would spend more time into looking into your mocking framework. They differ far more than testing frameworks. Some of the more popular are [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [NMock](http://www.nmock.org/), [Easy Mock](http://easymock.org/), [Rhino Mocks](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks), if you want free. For paid you have [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com) and [Just Mock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx). My current preference would be Moq because of the more fluent typing.

Comment: Of course in order to Mock effectively you will also need to have your code setup in a way that allows injecting that layer as opposed to your data layer. I would suggest a Dependency Injection framework such as [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) , [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html) , or [CastleWindsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) . I prefer Ninject for it's simplicity. StructureMap is probably the oldest and one of the most widely used.

Comment: If you are coding using TDD. You will end up with code that can be easily mocked.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input

Answer (score 4):

MSTest is built into Visual Studio 2010 and we've been using it at my companies since VS 2008. It is robust and simple unit testing framework and you don't have to run anything third-party.

Just create a new unit test project and you should be off to the races.

That said, I know a lot of people who use NUnit and are perfectly happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the recent testing-related cool things that came from Microsoft is [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/). Lifted from the project page:

> Pex automatically generates test
> suites with high code coverage. Right
> from the Visual Studio code editor,
> Pex finds interesting input-output
> values of your methods, which you can
> save as a small test suite with high
> code coverage. Microsoft Pex is a
> Visual Studio add-in for testing .NET
> Framework applications.

Definitely worth checking.